# why class for abc.aspx.cs is not visible in class of App_code folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't access the variable declared in New_Customer.aspx.cs ( reside in Member folder) to Senior.cs (reside in App_code folder).
My code for New_customer.aspx.cs is as follows

```
public partial class Member_New_Customer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string[] aid = new string[5];
public string[] name= new string[5] ;
}
```

and my code for Senior.cs is as follows

```
public class Senior
{   
    //here Member_New_Customer/New_Customer is not visible.

public Senior()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}
}
```

Comment: Why? The variable would be useless, and only useful when associated with a request?

Comment: If you try to access the variable do you get an error.

Comment: You can't. The dependencies can only go the other way. `App_Code` code is compiled into an assembly that then, other code (in code-behind, etc) can reference. At the time that the `App_Code` code is compiling, the code-behind code hasn't yet been compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices :

1) You create a static class (only 1 instance of the class for your program), which would be stupid if you want to store customers.

2) You create an instance of your class that way :

```
 Member_New_Customer myMemberNewCustomer = new Member_New_Customer();
 myMemberNewCustomer.name = "name";
```